# Plot closer lines in foreground with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to project some 3D paths with pyplot. I am running into the issue that pyplot will doesn't plot overlapping lines correctly. If i run the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# make figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])

# define 2 easily distiguishable paths
path1 = np.array(  [np.zeros(100),
                    np.linspace(0.5,-0.5,100),
                    np.ones(100)*0.5])

path2 = np.array(  [np.linspace(0.5,-0.5,100),
                    np.ones(100)*0.5,
                    np.zeros(100)])


#plot paths in order
ax.plot(path1[0], path1[1], path1[2], 'r')
ax.plot(path2[0], path2[1], path2[2], 'b')
plt.show()
```

I get the image below. You can see that, even though the blue line should be behind the red one, it is projected in front since it was plotted later. For more complicated paths this behaviour becomes quite unpredictable. Is there a way (either in pyplot or another library) to change the behaviour such that the closest line is always in the foreground?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a reasonable solution. If the observer position is set at the start, you can you the 'zorder' parameter of the plot function to get correct behaviour. It's a bit of a pain but it works.